# Action bar popup background is not changing

Tags: android

@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar

```
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/popupMenuStyle</item>
     <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.MyTheme.Widget</item>        
     <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@null</item>
     <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">45dp</item>
```

```
<style name="popupMenuStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyTheme.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:textColor">#0675bc</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

I have an activity which is having action bar overflow menu and my custom pop up menu I am using Theme.MyTheme.Widget in the above code it is working fine but the problem is I am using search view in action bar in another activity.Now the problem is if I am using the  above code to change the overflow menu background this changes are applying to the search bar also which I don't need

Comment: Are you supporting API 14+?

Comment: I am supporting API 15

Answer (score 0):

if you API is minimum API level 14 , you can change with this (worked for me).

```
<style name="Theme.myapp" parent="@style/Theme.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/myapp_DropDownNav</item>        
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/myapp.actionBarWidgetTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="myapp.actionBarWidgetTheme" parent="@style/Theme.">
     <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/myapp.Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner</item>
</style>

<style name="myapp_DropDownNav" parent="@style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_myapp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_myapp</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_myapp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_myapp</item>
</style>

<style name="myapp.Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner" parent="Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/myapp.TextAppearance.Widget.DropDownItem</item>
</style>

<style name="myapp.TextAppearance.Widget.DropDownItem" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.DropDownItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

if you are using ActionBarSherlock (minimun API level 9), try this:

```
   <style name="Theme.yourapp" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">  

    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Style</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Style</item> </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu.Style" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListPopupWindow">    
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/your_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownListView.Style" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/your_background</item>
    </style>
```

Hope it helps you!!